# Retrieve data for multiple single or reference without like operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, which looks like below. In the employee table instead mentioning the skills directly, I'm using as reference from another table.

**Question**:

```
select * from Employee where Skills = "1";
```

The above query will show the employee record who has ONLY the "Python" skill. Certainly, it won't show the other combination in which Python is included, such as "1,2" (Python, Java). How can i achieve this without using like operator, since in case if i have 10, 11, 21 in skills it'll be problem isn't it.

If you feel this way of using reference is difficult or not recommend, please suggest your idea :-)

Employee table:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| id  | Name        | Skills      |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | Xyz         | 1,2,4       |
| 2   | Xyy         | 1,3         |
| 3   | Abc         | 1,2,3       |
| 4   | Asd         | 1           |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

Skillset table:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | SkillSet    |
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | Python      |
| 2   | Java        |
| 3   | C           |
| 4   | PHP         |
+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Use this select * from Employee where Skills IN (Comma Separated skill Id like 1,2,4 or just 1);

Comment: ***This is really a bad design*** you should [Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it

Comment: You can't.  You need to re-factor your design; storing multiple values in a single field as a comma delimited string is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  You should have an `employee_skills {employee_id, skillset_id}` table that has one row per employee-skill combination.

Comment: @MatBailie, Thanks, in the method you suggested, we need to create another table! But, I wanted to eliminate the no. of tables in my schema (Believe me, in my real time project we have so many tables to handle). That's why asked is this kind of idea is good or is there any other better idea. In case, if there's no other possibilities, obviously will stick to the suggestion which you mentioned.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, point noted. :)

Comment: @ManivG - I can't comment on the rest of your schema.  Trying to avoid link tables, such as I mentioned, by squashing multiple fields in to one field, or multiple tables in to one table won't help you; it will lead you in to a complete mess.  I strongly suggest sticking with standard principles until you have it working, then looking to see if you have *very strong* reasons to attempt to denormalise anything.  *(But never use comma delimited strings to hold multiple searchable values, please.)*

Comment: As the others says, and as IndigoIdentity says in his answer, you need to normalize your database. Anyway, there could be another solution, what is an ultra ugly hack, and I do not recommend you: search for all cases, where 1 can be `WHERE skills LIKE '1,' OR skills LIKE ',1' OR skills LIKE ',1,' OR skills = 1;`

Comment: @lolka_bolka - You may as well simplify that down to `CONCAT(',', skills, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'` == `',1,2,3,4,' LIKE '%,1,%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from employee ;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | skills |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | xyz  | 1,2,4  |
|    2 | abc  | 1,3    |
|    3 | lmn  | 1,2,3  |
+------+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from skillset ;
+------+----------+
| id   | skillset |
+------+----------+
|    1 | Python   |
|    2 | Java     |
|    3 | C        |
|    4 | PHP      |
+------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This structure is similar to yours and to do query in these situation we can however use `find_in_set` but thats pretty inefficient , here are few examples

```
mysql> select e.id,
e.name, 
group_concat(s.skillset) as skillset 
from employee e join skillset s 
on find_in_set(s.id,e.skills) > 0 
where find_in_set(1,e.skills) > 0 
 group by e.id ;
+------+------+-----------------+
| id   | name | skillset        |
+------+------+-----------------+
|    1 | xyz  | Python,Java,PHP |
|    2 | abc  | C,Python        |
|    3 | lmn  | Java,Python,C   |
+------+------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select e.id,
e.name, 
group_concat(s.skillset) as skillset 
from employee e 
join skillset s on find_in_set(s.id,e.skills) > 0 
where find_in_set(2,e.skills) > 0  group by e.id ;
+------+------+-----------------+
| id   | name | skillset        |
+------+------+-----------------+
|    1 | xyz  | Python,PHP,Java |
|    3 | lmn  | C,Java,Python   |
+------+------+-----------------+
```

Now a proper normalization would make life much simpler and will have the following association table

```
mysql> select * from employee_skills; 
+------------+----------+
| idemployee | idskills |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        1 |
|          1 |        2 |
|          1 |        3 |
|          2 |        1 |
|          2 |        3 |
|          3 |        1 |
|          3 |        2 |
|          3 |        3 |
+------------+----------+
```

Now doing query will be much more efficient in this case

```
mysql> select e.id,
e.name,
s.skillset from employee e 
join employee_skills es on es.idemployee = e.id 
join skillset s on s.id = es.idskills where s.id = 1 ;
+------+------+----------+
| id   | name | skillset |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 | xyz  | Python   |
|    2 | abc  | Python   |
|    3 | lmn  | Python   |
+------+------+----------+
```

Using the last approach more complex calculations could be done pretty easily.

Comment: Why do you opt to use join?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity - As opposed to what specifically?  `JOIN vs INNER JOIN` or `JOIN vs ,`?

Comment: INNER JOIN as I have used.

Comment: `Inner join` and just `join` is same.

Comment: I see now thanks, inner join is the default type if no other type is specified for join.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity exactly !!

Comment: AbhikChakraborty, Thanks, I'm going to use the solution with normalization.
@MatBailie, Thanks for your suggestion mate !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others in the comments, this is not the most useful design choice as it would make it long winded to create a simple CRUD interface to interact with these values.

You would have ideally:

employee table:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | name        |
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | Bob         |
| 2   | Mary        |
+-----+-------------++
```

skillset table:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | skillset    |
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | Python      |
| 2   | Java        |
| 3   | C           |
| 4   | PHP         |
+-----+-------------+
```

employee_skillset table:

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| id  | employee_id   | skillset_id   |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| 1   | 1             | 1             |
| 2   | 1             | 2             |
| 3   | 1             | 4             |
| 4   | 2             | 1             |
| 5   | 2             | 3             |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

Then you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN employee_skillset es
ON e.id = es.employee_id    
WHERE es.skillset_id = "1";
```

You could use the skillset table in the CRUD interface as selectable / editable options.

**EDIT:**

It's easy enough to include a range of skills within this too using the **IN** clause:

```
WHERE es.skillset_id IN (1, 3, 4);
```