# How best to implement a one to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm building a Laravel 5 project with MySQL as the database system. In this project I'll have many educational videos, the total number is unknown, but it could grow large. This is my first big project, and I'm struggling with a particular issue:

- Each video has its own tags, the source link and the authors that made it. The source link will be unique but of course different
  people can author different videos.

I thought of using a table to make the relationship between the video id and its authors. Same thing for video tags and so on.
I'm afraid it won't be very performant. For example, in a given moment there could be 200 videos authored by 5 people, so I'd have 1000 rows. So just to know who authored a concrete video, I should have to go through a thousand rows.

I'm told that I should only put one value in each database field but, given the case, wouldn't it be less painful and efficient If I put an array of authors names in one field of the video table?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're going about this the wrong way. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891522/retrieve-data-for-multiple-single-or-reference-without-like-operator/29891902

Comment: BTW, MySQL is able to deal with an incredible amount of information efficiently (i query millions of records in seconds). You would have no issues with finding a few records in a few thousand. I get what you're saying though and yeah in the long run it would be a problem so try to fix issues like this now but do your research into schema first as detailed ones for this use likely already exist. Oh and if you ask a question on SO, post some code relating to the query - they do not take fondly to stories :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good question , but believe me ,MySQL is Power full DB to handle a millions of queries in less time.

I think you only need one row with several key fields to expand your sorting choice and satisfy users interests.

Some key field has to be created early on  , for example ,a Date of inserting a video,a field topic,a video size and so on.

my advice is to make several key fields as much as you can To avoid any stop with future changes in terms of sorting and classification.

So , try to gather a lot of suggestions from the users,authors,colleagues and all the beneficiaries from this project before starting upload vedios and make sure that you cover any expected type of change

moreover , later you can minimize useless key fields but after live & production experience