# Join two table mysql query return all user list values?

Tags: mysql

**Join two table MySQL query return all user list values.**
**Please correct this query or provide some query.**

Table1 : users

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name  | cource_id |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | ramalingam | 1,2,3,4   |
|       2 | yuvi       | 1         |
|       3 | Saravanan  | 1,2,3     |
|       4 | gandhi     | 1         |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Table2 : course

```
+-----------+-------------+
| cource_id | cource_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | php         |
|         2 | wordpress   |
|         3 | seo         |
|         4 | magento     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Output

```
--------------------------------------
user_id | user_name | cource_id
--------------------------------------
1       | ramalingam| php,wordpress,seo,magnto
2       | yuvi      | php
3       | Saravanan | php,wordpress,seo
4       | gandhi    | php
```

### This my query

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cource_name)as course_name
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN course as c ON c.cource_id = u.user_id
```

Thank you for any help I can get on this...

Comment: Thats a bad DB design and you should never store comma separated data. You need to normalize it. Here is one of my answer with same situation and how to do normalization and get the desired result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071597/mysql-split-string-and-select-with-results/30071995#30071995

Comment: Here is another one similar to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891522/retrieve-data-for-multiple-single-or-reference-without-like-operator/29892114#29892114

Comment: where is the `department` table and what is the purpose of it? shall this table be part of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general DB design is bad, don't use comma separated lists at all. Hovewer you should use `FIND_IN_SET()` in your JOIN clause in order to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.cource_name) AS course_name
FROM
    users AS u
LEFT JOIN cource AS c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.cource_id, u.cource_id)
GROUP BY
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name
```

Output is:

```
+---------+------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | user_name  | course_name               |
+---------+------------+---------------------------+
|       1 | ramalingam | php,wordpress,seo,magento |
|       2 | yuvi       | php                       |
|       3 | Saravanan  | php,wordpress,seo         |
|       4 | gandhi     | php                       |
+---------+------------+---------------------------+
4 rows in set
```